# Using what dataset has the get DefaultPeopleDetector() SVM been trained on?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
```

I have seen these two lines of code in may online forums but I don't understand where the SVM vector comes from, i.e. what was the training data that was used to train this SVM and can I find that data and source code anywhere?

And also why does the SVM vector have a length of 3781 for a 64x128 image?

Some insight into this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: check http://answers.opencv.org/question/104175/which-dataset-is-used-for-training-the-defaultpeopledetector-hogdescriptor/ and http://answers.opencv.org/question/26623/defaultpeopledetector-true-pedestrian-height/ ...

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using pre-trained people detector as SVM. You can read about it in the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-getdefaultpeopledetector). I don't know the way that they trained it (The algorithms, parameters). But according to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/104175/which-dataset-is-used-for-training-the-defaultpeopledetector-hogdescriptor/) answer, it was trained with [Daimler Pedestrian Detection Dataset](http://www.gavrila.net/Research/Pedestrian_Detection/Daimler_Pedestrian_Benchmark_D/Daimler_Mono_Ped__Detection_Be/daimler_mono_ped__detection_be.html).

`cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector()` will return a array with size 3781 in size. Those are coefficients that are used by SVM to classify people. It has nothing to do with the input image that you are using.

And most importantly you can train a SVM as you like to detect another object and use as the SVM detector. Check [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56655/how-to-use-a-custom-svm-with-hogdescriptor-in-python/) answer for more.

Comment: in fact it says that the `getDaimlerPeopleDetector` is trained with daimler dataset, but the first one (`getDefaultPeopleDetector`) is probably trained with INRIA dataset (from original hog pedestrian detection paper) but not documented.